# Is node.js behind Apache much slower than the node.js HTTP-server?

Tags: performance, apache, http, node.js

Is this much slower than direct Access?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:23232/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn't be much slower. It would only differ by the tiny fraction it takes for Apache to proxy your request which compared to the time it takes for Node.js to process your request is most likely even hard to measure.

However, you'd probably want to use [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) and [`ProxyPassReverse`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) instead of a rewrite so that Apache acts as a real proxy instead.

Comment: Is it right, that i can`t do ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse in .htaccess?

Comment: @raxer: Yeah, they are only available in the server config. For the `.htaccess` you can use the rewrite.

Comment: Thank you. Question is answered.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, I found a nice writeup of getting node working with apache [here](http://davybrion.com/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache/).  Not my blog, so I'm not self-promoting, and the use of proxyPass as Marcus said, is preferred.